# Android : no such file name or directory

Tags: android, ftp, filestream

I'm writing an app for android which has to download a file from an FTP-server .
It seems that I can read the file from the FTP-server without any problem , but when I try to open it , the app throws the following error :  no such file name or directory .

The code  :

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient  ;  // The ftpclient of apache commons
// all the code for connecting to the server 

FileOutputStream fOut  = openFileOutput("ipfile.text" , Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) ; 
    ftp.retrieveFile("ip.text" , fOut) ; 



    Log.v("As" , "Read file with succes from drivehq") ;

    String helpStr = "ERROR" ; 
    byte[] inputBuffer = new byte [1024] ; 

     try{
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/data/data/ipfile.text") ;
         fis.read(inputBuffer) ;
         fis.close() ; 
         helpStr = new String (inputBuffer) ; 
         Log.v("As" , "Read file from " + helpStr) ; 



     }
     catch(Exception e) {
         Log.v("As" ," Unable to read the ip-file " + e.getMessage()) ;  
     }
```

The Logcat :

```
 02-28 21:31:38.741: V/As(3992): Logged on with success to drivehq
02-28 21:31:38.911: V/As(3992): Changed working directory on drivehq
02-28 21:31:39.972: V/As(3992): Read file with succes from drivehq
02-28 21:31:39.972: V/As(3992):  Unable to read the ip-file  ipfile.text (No such file or directory)
```

Thanks , Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing your FileOutputStream "fOut"

Likely that stream has locked the file causing you to not be able to read the file despite it being created.

```
FileOutputStream fOut  = openFileOutput("ipfile.text" , Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) ; 
ftp.retrieveFile("ip.text" , fOut) ; 
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

Additionally, you should be opening your file in a similar fashion you opened the output file using

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileOutput("ipfile.text");
```

This may actually be the reason your read isn't working rather than the reason above.

Comment: Thanks !  It was indeed the last reason :)

Comment: Great! Don't forget the first part though! You definitely want to close an output stream once you are done with it. openFileOutput gives you access to your applications private context files. Using FileInputStream("/data/data/ipfile.text") won't work since it basically doesn't have permission to open the file that way